# TSQL Group BY Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

i would like to ask some help from you guys. i am making a daily sales report and got some problem with **GROUP BY** clause.

here is the sample table:

```
 ItemName   Quantity   Price
 ===========================
  ItemA        5       150.00
  ItemB        6       100.00
  ItemA        2       125.00
  ItemD        1       110.00
  ItemB        1       100.00
  ItemD        3       110.00
```

and i want to have results formatted like this:

```
 RESULT:
 ItemName   Quantity   Price
 =============================
  ItemA        2       125.00
  ItemA        5       150.00
  ItemB        7       100.00
  ItemD        4       110.00
```

As you can see, ItemA occurs twice since it differs in Price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemName, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity, Price
FROM ItemTable
GROUP BY ItemName, Price
ORDER BY ItemName, Price
```

Comment: thanks, i was not able to add Price field in Group By clause.

Answer (score 1):

So, something like this:

```
SELECT ItemName, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity, Price
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ItemName, Price
```